# Understanding the theoretical run time of a function with nested loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I've been trying to understand Big-O notation. Earlier today, I was given a function to practice with and told that it has a `O(n^5)`. I've tried calculating it on my own but don't know if I've calculated `T(n)` correctly.

Here are my two questions:

1) Did I calculate `T(n)` correctly and if not then what did I do wrong?

2) Why do we only concern ourselves with the variable to the highest power?

```
1    sum = 0;                           //1                 =   1
2    for( i=0;  i < n;  i++)            //1 + n + 2(n-1)    =   1+n+2n-2            = 3n-1
3     for (j=0; j <  i*i;  j++)         //n + n*n + 2n(n-1))=   n+ n^2 + 2n^2-2n    = 3n^2 -n
4      for (k=0; k < j;  k++)           //n + n*n + 4n(n-1))=   n + n*n +4n*n-4n    = 5n^2 -3n
5           sum++;
6           k++; 
7       j++; 
8   i++;
// so now that I have simplified everything I multiplied the equations on lines 2-4 and added line 1
// T(n) = 1 + (3n-1)(3n^2-n)(5n^2 -3n) = 45n^5 -57n^4 +23n^3 -3n^2 + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innermost loop runs `j` times.
Second loop runs for `j = 0 to i^2` -> sum of integers.
Outer loop runs to `n` -> sum of squares and 4th powers of integers.

[image]

We only take the highest power because as `n` approaches infinity, the highest power of `n` (or order) will always dominate, irrespective of its coefficient.